# Does changing race allow for the increase of ability scores beyond 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ability-scores, racial-traits

The *reincarnate* spell replaces your racial traits, within which ability score increases are included. **Is a racial ability score increase capped at 20 like a class ASI**?

For example, if I have 20 Charisma as a Half-Orc and am reincarnated into a Half-Elf would I then have 22 Charisma?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Ability scores have a maximum of 20 for player characters.

From the first chapter in the *Player's Handbook*, section *Beyond 1st Level*:

> [...] Some of these features allow you to increase your ability scores, either increasing two scores by 1 each or increasing one score by 2. **You can't increase an ability score above 20.** *(PHB, 15)*

But, one might argue, this only applies to *ability score increases* from leveling up. So what about your case, when someone gains a racial ability that increases their ability score while they are already at 20?

From *Chapter 7: Using Ability Scores* in the *Player's Handbook*:

> A score of 10 or 11 is the normal human average, but adventurers and many monsters are a cut above average in most abilities. A score of 18 is the highest that a person usually reaches. **Adventurers can have scores as high as 20**, and monsters and divine beings can have scores as high as 30. *(PHB, 173)*

Adventurers, such as a player character, can go *as high as 20*, but no higher.† To my knowledge, level 20 Barbarians are the sole exception thanks to the *Primal Champion* trait, which increases their maximum Strength and Constitution (as well as the scores themselves) by 4.

In your case, rules as written, a Half-Orc with a 20 in Charisma who is reincarnated into a Half-Elf would still be at 20 Charisma.

† <sub>As always, there are exceptions to the rule. There do exist magical means to increase ability scores above 20; for example, the *Tome of Leadership and Influence* for Charisma.</sub>

Comment: @Medix2 Yes, which is addressed in my answer. "Outside of some sort of magical effect"...

Comment: A bit of a nitpick but inwoikd say "capped at 20 for all abilities." Stats (aka game staitlstics) include things like HP which is certainly not capped at 20

Comment: Does everything that can raise something over 20 say so explicitly?

Comment: @JollyJoker Yes, otherwise it wouldn't raise the cap.

Comment: @Baron Not everything that raises a stat above 20 also raises the cap. See: Star Card

Comment: @Medix2 Sure, except for the part where it explicitly states that it can raise a stat above 20...

Comment: @Baron My point is that it still isn't raising the cap (I mean, technically there is no cap for magic items unless the item explicitly makes one)